# How to to execute a dialog command, and have it return to the original screen?

Tags: bash, shell, dialog, terminal

Newbie here, not sure how to ask this.

### Short version

What is the trick to execute a shell command, upon finishing, it will return to the original screen?

### Long version

I am wring a shell script using `dialog`, say it will open a console based UI, then when I exit it, it will looks like:

```
$ ./run_a_script_containing_dialog.sh
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+.......
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++ A BLUE BACKGROUND DIALOG ++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+.......
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
$ (Upon finishing, prompt would be here)
```

What I really want is this:

```
$ ./run_a_script_containing_dialog.sh
$ (Dialog is still opened as normal, but upon finishing, prompt would be here)
```

I'd like to see a kind of behavior just like what we typically see in using `man`, when you press `q`, it will return to your original screen.

### Another version

*PS:  Please forgive me if you think the solution of this would be totally different than the above.*

How to write a shell script to achieve this effect? Let's say this script will just simply list the files in the current folder, but it will list them in a new screen.

```
$ ./a_personal_ls.sh (a new screen will open and list the files in $PWD)
$ (Pressing `q` will cause the new screen disappear, and prompt will be here)
```

Is this doable in shell scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the somewhat confusingly named `--keep-tite` option to `dialog` (as the first option).